# Is it possible to (and how can you) run a vba function in Excel when it is stored in a field on a remote database?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am creating an XLS which varying departments/personnel will use to view varying reports which are applicable specifically to that department, person or everything.

Because the number of reports will be quite alot, I want to limit the size of the file.  The available reports are currently pulled from an SQL Server and listed, to which the user then enters an 'X' next to the required report and hits GENERATE.

The report is generated in a worksheet which is created on the fly and deleted when the file is closed.

At this time, I still have to have a module for each specific report required.  Some are a few lines, others much more, such as pivot tables which require alot of config or general tables that need a lot of formatting etc.

Is it possible to retrieve vba from a Database as text and then run it as VBA?

Answer (score 1):

You can add write code with VBA dynamically but you'll need to allow access to programmatic access to the VB Object model and change various trust settings depending on the version of Excel your users will be using. Virus scanners can also delete modules which reference the VB Object model since they see them as a security threat.

So yes, you can run code from code stored remotely by creating the VBA code from a string on the fly

Chip Pearson has this pretty well covered here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

That said, it's not really something I'd recommend, VBA code doesn't take up much space, it's only text after all, so I'd be tempted to leave all the code in the workbook, it's more simple, easier for users and has fewer complications.

If you don't want to do this, I'd suggest you put all your code in an add-in, it's then separate from the workbooks you create, but allows all the functionality with none of the drawbacks of dynamically generating code

Comment: Thanks, not the answer I was hoping for, but it tells me what I need to know.